# R-code table does not stratify correctly (using tbl_strata + tbl_summary)

Tags: r, dplyr, gtsummary, gt

I would like to create a table that is stratified by both "group_category" AND "Sex" (variables named relevant to my data frame). I need all variables to calculate mean(se).

The main issue is that one variable within the second code below is calculating n(%) rather than mean(se).

The first code below is the table grouped by "group_category" to show what my "simple" code looks like:

```
cyto_table <- ccf.data.merge %>% #data frame
  select(group_category, delta_TNFa, delta_IFNy, delta_IL1B, delta_IL2, delta_IL6, delta_IL8) %>% #variables I want for my table
      tbl_summary(
        by = group_category, #group_category = treatment A and B
        statistic = list(all_continuous() ~ "{mean} ({se})"), missing = "no") %>%
      modify_header(label ~ "**Variable**") %>%
      bold_labels()
cyto_table
```

the result table from the "simple" code above:

[image]

To create the table I want, I looked up a code to work off of as a template and in the end, created the below code:

```
cyto_table <- ccf.data.merge %>%
  select(group_category,Sex,delta_TNFa, delta_IFNy, delta_IL1B, delta_IL2, delta_IL6, delta_IL8) %>% #variables I want for my table
  dplyr::mutate(
    Sex = factor(Sex, labels = c("Female", "Male"))) %>% #I am not sure the reasoning behind this line. the original code had this, I'm not gonna argue.
  tbl_strata(
    strata = group_category, #here the code is layering the able to be stratified by the treatments (A and B).
    ~.x %>% #I believe this line is making a function for tbl_summary to pass through.
      tbl_summary(
        by = Sex, #finally Sex is added here so that the data is then split by Sex within each treatment.
        statistic = list(all_continuous() ~ "{mean} ({se})"), missing = "no") %>%
      modify_header(label ~ "**Variable**") %>%
      bold_labels())
cyto_table
```

The table that results from the second code (above:)

[image]

The image shows that "delta-IL1B" is calculated as n(%) rather than the mean(se) I coded for. Why is one variable calculating n(%)? How can I fix this?

I do not know how to create a dataset to reproduce this exact problem.

Comment: you can `dput(ccf.data.merge)` in the r console and then paste those results into your question. That would give use access to your data. Also please include all packages you are using

Comment: @Mike, thank you for responding! I can't post the data because the data has not been published yet. I will attempt to recreate the problem with other data.

Comment: Use the tbl_summary(type=) argument to force a continuous summary